# How to create dedicated resource pool for Health check within ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The reason why I want to achieve this is that, when the system is under pressure, the endpoints supposed to respond to Production queries/commands may hang, in this moment, I still want the Health endpoints to continue to serve requests.

.NET does not seem to offer the possibility to create a dedicated thread pool like in JVM. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no way to do this, the healthcheck is worked as a special endpoint in the application.